Using AI Assistance for Drafting Recommendation Letters: Risks and Considerations
I am applying for a PhD program and have reached out to three professors to write recommendation letters for me. Since they are quite busy, they have asked me to draft the letters myself. Can I use ChatGPT to help me write them? Would this result in the admission committee identifying AI involvement or noticing a high similarity rate among the three letters, potentially leading to rejection?

The high similarity rate is presumably also an issue if you personally draft all three letters yourself too

For a starter, your question title reads suspiciously like what ChatGPT would generate.

I don't believe that a single professor, let alone all three, would have you draft your own letter of recommendation.

@kjhughes This is apparently a common practice in some places, although I personally find it baffling--why have letters at all?

While you might get away with it, I would recommend against it, partly for the reasons you give. But who knows your qualifications for graduate study better than you do? Do you think some AI (which, in spite of its name, isn't intelligent) knows more about you and your goals and background?
If you use it for a first draft, it might be safe enough to give an outline,  but so would reading a few successful letters of others from the past.
At this point in time, AI is, IMO, mostly hype put out by those who want to sell it. It makes egregious errors that if not caught by an actually intelligent being can do great harm.
True AI is always ten years in the future, and it has been for at least the last 50 years. Interesting, but not to be trusted.
I suggest, instead, that you make a list of your qualifications and goals and then draft something around those. And note that the letters from the three or so writers had better not seem alike. Maybe a list of things for each writer would be enough, perhaps with some guidance about what you think should be emphasized.
I've never asked people to write their own letters, but, for those who have been away for a while, I might ask them to remind me of some of our interactions. This helps me personalize the letter. Being busy, we don't always remember as much as we like.

+1 for the answer. Not sure AI is still 10 years away. The current crop of "AI" apps is (reportedly) very good as a coding assistant and (some say_ at summarizing documents that people wrote too wordily. Of course you can choose not to call that artificial intelligence.

As a senior dev who’s played around with AI as a dev assistant, it could be helpful for writing very simple boilerplate code, though personally getting inline code recommendations would break my train of thought. But AI writing code with any complexity at all has in my experience been a trainwreck. It can appear to do a good job at times while writing code that if actually put into production would lead to possibly career-limiting outcomes. All in all, using AI for real work except the most trivial of tasks has proved frustrating and not worth the effort.

I wholeheartedly agree. I like to play around with ChatGPT as a toy, but the one time I thought I might try it for real work, it produced output that was wrong in ways that are sanctionable and could have been disastrous if I hadn't caught the problems. In the end, writing it myself was faster and safer than using AI. Other lawyers have failed to catch the problem and have in fact been sanctioned for mistakes made by AI that they failed to correct.

It's problematic that you are being asked to draft your own letters of recommendation, but I suppose that part of the situation is outside your control, so... it is what it is. You could gently push back and suggest some alternatives, like giving them bullet points of objective achievements they have witnessed working with you, or meeting them and discussing the letters in person. But you need to assess yourself how much pushback of this sort is politically feasible with these professors.
Regarding the use of AI to do (some of) the draft writing, my main worry would not be whether the committee is going to recognise AI writing, but whether the letter of recommendation ends up saying things about you that are both true and that the person sending the letter (who I will henceforth simply call the "letter sender") could plausibly have written about you. Just like anybody else other than the letter sender, any AI can only speculate about what the letter sender has seen of your work and what the letter sender thinks of your work, unless you or the letter sender tell it. If you let it speculate, you are bound to end up with stuff that is either wrong, or bland, or generic, or all of these.
The main problem of your situation is that you are asked to draft your own letters and that you are likely to be poorly equipped to do that, because as a letter writer for yourself, you have an obvious conflict of interest, it is difficult to assess one's own work objectively, you do not exactly know what your teachers privately think about you or what they know of your work, and finally, you likely have no experience in writing these letters. Additionally, the letter senders have put you in the somewhat uncomfortable situation that you are asked to draft three letters, which of course might cause the problem of an unnatural degree of correlation between them that you already mentioned, but which is totally independent of AI.
Given this analysis, I think AIs like ChatGPT could be helpful in your situation, but I would think not by producing those drafts in one go. I could imagine something like the following might yield results that are at least somewhat useful:

Before you prompt the AI to do any drafting, describe the situation fully to it. Any context will be useful. That includes the context that you are asked to draft these letters for yourself.
Ask it to ask you a list of questions that have objective short answers and that are necessary as context for drafting the letters. Remind the model that this is not limited to stuff in your CV and the position that you are applying for, but also about your relationship with the letter writer. Try to answer those questions as precisely as possible.
When all that information has been gathered, ask it to first write an outline of the letter. Use common sense to judge if those outlines make sense in your discipline.
Write a draft letter yourself that tries to cover all the items in the outline as objectively as possible. Then let the LLM write a draft and compare.
Write final drafts yourself and send them off. Mark them clearly as drafts and mention (very politely) in your message to the potential letter writer that as discussed, you are attaching a draft which might need adjustment according to their judgement. I would probably also mention explicitly that you do not and cannot know what their judgement of your work is and that therefore any part of the drafts that evaluates your work (as opposed to just listing objective facts) will need adjustment.

I think that kind of workflow would to some limited extent mitigate the problems with lack of objectivity in self-assessment and not knowing what to do in a letter of recommendation. It may also mitigate some LLM-specific problems (like willingness to speculate plausibly when data is lacking) and may produce writing that looks more polished than what you would draft all on your own.
Note that the latter has probably some positive sides (well... more polished text), but could also have some plausible negative sides (the worst one is probably the possibility that a well-written but factually weak letter might convince a potential letter sender to endorse the draft unchanged without deeply engaging with the content).

I recommend against using GenAI for such a task: You are supposed to provide a draft, not a final letter, for which the strengths and weaknesses of GenAI are exactly counter to what you need.
A draft for a recommendation letter should cover your unique interactions with the letter signatory. A draft should not have polished wording that is at odds with the signatory's style.
GenAI has no idea about the former* but will go out of its way with the latter.
So don’t sweat it, do an honest attempt of writing down the relevant facts and let the signatory handle what they – hopefully – do best, namely using not just polished but proper wording.**

*Which won’t stop it from making up generic "facts" with confidence, mind.
**Incidentally, they might just use GenAI for this since they know what to look out for.
